# How to change language in warnings in VSCode?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am using VSCode while coding in unity. Even though the language of the VSCode is English, the warnings as in the screenshot below are in Turkish. How can I change it to English?

I have tried pressing F1, writing Configure Display Language, and choosing "en", and after I restart, the problem persists. [image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Diagnosing (human spoken) Language Issues

---

> Okay, so there are a few different ***"things"*** that could factor into, ***"why your **Hover Widget** is displaying Turk, rather than English"***. In order to learn what the root cause is with certainty, there are steps you need to iterate through in order to diagnose the issue. Below I will go over those steps, and I will mention certain possible issues that could cause the problem along the way.

---

###### *Here we go.*

## #1 Configure V.S. Code to Use English as the Default Language.

---

> Okay so I know you did this, but I need you to do it again just for certainties sake. Even the most fundamental of solutions need to be covered when diagnosing any software issue, especially configuration issues. Also, check and see, while you preform the steps below, if you are able to select any other languages than *English*. If you are able to select something other than English, *namely **Turk** in this instance*, then that means you have the language pack installed, and Ill talk more about that in the next step **Step (2a)**.

###### Follow Steps A - E then refer to *"Progress Review #1"*

---

**A -** Press **[F1]** to open your **Command Palette**

**B -** Once the *Command Palette* drops open, start typing "display", you should see the options available start to dwindle as quick input filters out the options that don't have title's matching the spelling of your input.

**C -** You should see the option labeled: **"Configure Display Language"** — select that option

**D -** Press the **[ENTER]** key, and a list of installed languages by locale will be displayed for you. Use your **[MOUSE]**, or **[ARROW KEYS]** to  highlight and select **ENGLISH**.

**E -** Completely close all VSCode instances that you have open , wait 3 seconds then open a single instance of VSCode.

---

##### Progress Review #1

> At this point, we should be able to know with, 100% certainty, that the language VSCode is set too is ENGLISH". Knowing that certain, ***"possible causes"*** are scratched of the list — *"the all possible causes list"* — helps to hone in, and narrow down what could be causing the issue. And if this doesn't make sense now, it will shortly I promise.

*[This link leads to an anchor on the V.S. Code website, that covers the steps [A, B, C, D, & E] in a more in-depth guide. If you already need more help click on this link.](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/locales#_changing-the-display-language)*

## #2a Check if You Have the Turk Language-pack.

###### Okay remember above when I said — "see if you can select any other language?" — here is why:

Open the **V.S. Code Extension View** by clicking on the **Extension View Icon** located on the **Activity-bar**...

---

#### [image: VSCode Extension Icon] *V.S. Code extension icon*

---

...or open it via the keyboard shortcut: **[CTRL]+[SHIFT]+[X]**. Once open search for the ***"Turkish Language Pack"***. If it shows that you are able to install it great, however, if there is an option for uninstalling it, or you see a gear icon next to the Language-pack extension, then that means you still have the language-pack downloaded, and installed, as an extension on your machine.

##### IF YOU HAVE A NON-ENGLISH LANGUAGE PACK THIS PART IS VERY IMPORTANT!

###### However, if you don't have the language-pack, skip the rest of step 2 (#2b), and continue to: *"Step-#2 Progress Review"*.

#### #2b Uninstall All Non-English Language-packs

---

**A -** Okay so, as I described ABOVE(^^) search for the turk language pack.

**B -** Once the language pack is in the extension menu, click the little icon that resembles a gear. The gear should be located on the left side of language-pack's extensions card, if you don't see it, you probably don't have your sidebars view wide enough, try increasing the width of the side bar. this is l.

**C -** Once you click on the gear a menu will drop open, choose Uninstall from the drop-down menu. This will uninstall the extension.

**D -** After the uninstall, you will be prompted to reload VS Code via a small reload button. Click the button to reload VSCode, or close & reopen the editor.

---

##### Progress Review #2

> At this point you should be able, with 100% certainty, know that the only language-pack installed is English. This is where things get interesting. Because at this point this point we know that V.S. Code isn't configured to use another language, and it doesn't even have the software to display another language.
>
> > ***"So then at this point is it safe to say that this is not an issue with VSCode?***"
> >
> > __"You might think so, but actually there is one other thing that might be causing this on V.S. Code's side."
>
> ##### Continue to Step #3

## #3 Clearing the Editors Cache/History.

So the first thing to do is clear your editors history, this can be done through VSCode.

**A -** Open the quick menu via [F1] Key and type ***"Clear Editor"***. Your options should filter as you type ***"Clear Editor"***

**B -** Select ***`Clear Editor Histor`*** by focusing on it in the list, and pressing enter.

**C -** Close V.S. Code, then reopen it. Don't use the "reload window" command, actually close the editor, and reopen it.

VSCode .caches data in locations, other than the .cache we just cleared using the ***"Clear File History"*** tool. There is cached blob-files located below:

###### This in not 3 different file locations, it is one file location per platform. The file-paths are suppose to be equivalents for each platform, however, I can only guarantee the path for Ubuntu Linux Distro's.

1. Windows-10 & Window 7 %APPDATA%\Code
2. macOS $HOME/Library/Application Support/Code/
3. Ubuntu/Linux $HOME/.config/Code/User

Here is another Directory that contains cached data, but before you minimize the browser, and start deleting stuff, read the rest of the answer (Progress Review #3).

1. `"C:\Users\me\AppData\Roaming\.cache"`
2. `"~/.cache"` Directory.

###### Mac users need to find there directory because I know nothing about Apple Products (& I never will).

---

##### Progress Review #3

> At this point you have done nearly all you can do on the VSCode side. If you are still experiencing an issue, their is a small chance it could be because of cached data in one of the file locations above. Personally I clear those caches out occasionally. I usually delete all the blobs from **Ubuntu/Linux: `$HOME/.config/Code/User`**. The other directory that holds cached files (the last one I mentioned, are the standard cache-directories for Windows & Ubuntu. Now, the standard cache for Ubuntu and windows can, and should be cleaned with a tool. I suggest if you delete anything else from caches on your machine, you use a tool that has decent positive feedback written about it on different arbitrary blogs or whatever.
>
> Whether You cleared your machines cache or not at this point, if your still getting Turk displayed on your machine, and I don't think you will at this point, but if you are: You need to go to github and create a new issue for the VS Code team to look at, they will solve this problem. If you do create an issue, please keep this answer updated in the comments, so I and other bi-lingual developers know what happens if the stumble upon this Q&A.

---

###### [Create a New Issue for V.S. Code on the V.S. Code GitHub Page](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues)

---

Comment: None of the solutions worked, however, thank you for your effort. I am accepting this answer

Comment: @MustafaYaşar Thats not good. Its important to get this fixed. Have you created an issue @ ___https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues___ ???

Answer (score 0):

I know this is late, but if someone else has this issue in the future, here's what has worked for me:

- You can either chagne the display language for your entire system to English in Windows settings, which is quite bothersome,
- or go to the install folder for VS Code, then to the "locales" folder and delete the language you don't want to be displayed, in this case "tr.pak".